# Angular5 - How to detect empty or deleted field in mat-autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, angular-material, angular5, mat-autocomplete

This is my html which contains the material autocomplete.

```
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'autocomplete'">
    <div [ngClass]="(filter.cssClass || 'col-md-4') + ' mt-2 pt-1'">
        <div class="filter-key-label">
            {{filter.columnTitle}}
        </div>
        <div class="filter-form-control d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-left">
        <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" ng-model="blah">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of getOptionsTypeAhead(filter.key) | async" [value]="option" (onSelectionChange)="typeaheadChange($event, filter.key)">
                {{ option }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Currently I am able to detect **only selection changes** using `onSelectionChange` but it so not detects if the field is empty initially or when after having selected an item and then deleting it, I do not select anything and shift focus out of the input field.

**How do I detect that?**

I tried `onkeypress`, `ng-change` coupled with `ng-model` (was not very sure how to use that) and `change` but nothing worked. Is there some provision already present by the library or do we detect the change and input field value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved it! It was `change` all the time.

The best part is that it doesn't behave like `onkeypress` and only fires when there is an `blur` event.

I changed my `<input>` like this:

```
<input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" (change)="handleEmptyInput($event, filter.key)">
```

The controller looks something like this:

```
handleEmptyInput(event: any, key: string){
  if(event.target.value === '') {
    delete this.filtersApplied[key];
  }
}
```

Just like how I wanted to capture instances of empty fields or blank values :)

Comment: I tried follow this example, but when I enter with value in mat-autocomplete the input not working. If I select one item (without using autocomplete, it's working).

Comment: It's not made to detect key presses, it only works when you enter or delete some value and shift the focus out of the field.

Answer (score 0):

I still prefer (input)-event, because of the instant reaction.
But in my case I needed a programmatic solution, because I needed to pass the autocomplete-object (MatAutocomplete) to an uncoupled component (for more flexibility). This worked for me pretty good that way:

```js
@Input() matAutocomplete: MatAutocomplete = null;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  if (this.matAutocomplete) {
this.matAutocomplete.optionSelected.subscribe((evt: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) => {
  const val = evt.option.value;
  // here you can do whatever you like with this value. 
  // probably trigger the event, that is binded via (change) or (input) with the input-field
});
  }
}
```